# Problem with JTextPane - cursor Position at the end

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a JTextpane that I had populated it from DB.

The problem is when I set text, and when it's long, the JTextPane show the text from the end like in the snapshot.

How can I do ?? I tried `setCursor()` but I seem it isn't the right method.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textPane.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
textPane.setText(...);
```

See [Text Area Scrolling](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for more info.

Comment: +1 my learn item of the day - looks like I was still in 1.4 age :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
recordTP = new JTextPane();
    recordTP.setText(" from client:");
    recordTP.setEditable(false);
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)recordTP.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, it will be more helpful , if you can explain a little  bit ... Thank you for the answer